# how to adapt an unordered STL container to store only Values of a Key-Value pair?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, unordered-map, unordered-set

The new C++11 standard has unordered containers. In particular, the `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>` stores a `std::pair<Key, Value>` in a location based on `std::hash<Key>` (default hash function). Similarly, the `std::unordered_set<Key>` stores a Key in a location based on `std::hash<Key>`.

My question is: how can one store **only** the Value of a Key-Value pair, in a location based on `std::hash<Key>`? This would be useful if one uses a **perfect hash function**, i.e. one for which different Keys map to different hash indices (so there is never collision resolution required).

An unordered_set only uses the key, and an unordered_map uses both the key and the value, so the unordered STL containers in the new C++11 standard do not seem to allow such customization. What would be a good way to get such a data structure from the existing STL containers?

More generally, how can one store a `std::pair<T, Value>` in a location based on `std::hash<Key>`, where `T` is a type representing a signature of the Key? E.g. if Key is a large data structure, I would like to compute a 64-bit hash key and split this into two 32 bit parts: the upper 32 bits together with the Value form a `std::pair<uint32_t, Value>`, and the lower 32 bits determine the location where this pair is stored.

An application where this would be useful is e.g. computer chess, where a position (several kilobytes in some programs) as the Key type is hashed into a 64-bit key, of which only the upper 32 bits and some search related information as the Value type are stored as a `std::pair` (usually only 16 bytes in total) in a location based on the lower 32 bits of the hash key.

Comment: If `Key` is a large data structure as you posit, how it is being stored now?  Is there no value in actually storing it?  How intensive is it to build `hash<Key>`?  I am failing to see what you cannot due with `set` given the `Key` as part of the value, or what there is to gain over `map`.  Your example of saving 16bits of a 64bit value is not strong enough to convince me its worth the effort.

Comment: So you want something that uses hash<Key> to determine the position of where to put Value, without storing hash<key> anywhere?

Comment: Storing the key is an implementation requirement. It wouldn't be reasonable to do a hash table without it, because you need to check for multiple hashes going to a single bucket.

Comment: @Chad: I want to store 16 bytes (not bits!) of information about a struct of several kilobytes, without having to store the entire struct. Computing `hash<Key>` is cheap as it can be done incrementally (so-called Zobrist hashing), but that is beside the point.

Comment: A chess position isn't several kilobytes in length, or do you mean an entire game rather than just a position?

Comment: @dreamlax: yes, without storing the full Key. Either only the Value or a `std::pair<T,Value>` where T is a much smaller type than Key (in the chess example, T is 32 bits, and Key is several kilobytes).

Comment: @Mark Ransom: yes, that's why I generalized the initial question. For collision testing within buckets of a `std::pair<T, Value>`, the comparison would be done using `std::equal_to<T>`.

Comment: @dreamlax: yes, a chess position can be compressed to much less, but in a chess program, one stores a lot of intermediate tables (attack information, evaluation terms, history of the entire game, etc.). Even so, hashing only the minimal amount necessary to recognize the position would still be about 200 bytes, rather than the 4 byte signature used in most programs. For high performance programs, the size of the data stored matters quite a bit!

Comment: So... you want a hash of a hash (i.e. hash the chess position, then use part of that hash to store with the value)?

Comment: @rhalbersma - A chess program wouldn't use a an unordered_map, but a fixed structure with a single digit bucket size. Whatever size the table is, it will fill up quickly and you have to start replacing entries. An unordered_map will have poor performance once it is filled up.

Comment: @Bo Persson: yes, I know about the fixed size: essentially, a chess program's hash table is to std::unordered_map as std::array is to std::vector. That difference is about the resize policy rather than the indexing/addressing, so I guess another gripe with std::unordered_map is that it does not provide customization for collision resolution either! I have a working fixed size hash table for my program, but I wanted to adapt one of the new STL containers to see if they could replace my own implementation.

Comment: @rhalbersma: The STL containers are *general purpose* containers. This doesn't sound so general purpose-y. :)

Comment: @Mark Ransom: added comment about perfect hashing in the original question (collision resolution would not be necessary for such hash functions).

Comment: @Xeo: general purpose should mean good default behavior but also customizability along many different behavioral dimension. The STL containers only provide the hash / comparison / allocator functions as customization points, but not what is being stored, or how collisions are to be resolved. Wikipedia has a long [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) about different collision strategies, but these cannot be tried with unordered_map. I find that not very general purpose.

Comment: @rhalbersma : You're describing 'extensible', not 'general-purpose'. The latter merely means what's good enough for most people most of the time; what you're looking for falls well outside of that.

Comment: @ildjarn: an old [post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2002/12/41112.php) on the Boost mailinglist states: "Although a hash table library with a policy-based addressing scheme (i.e. separate chaining policy, open addressing (with various probing algorithms)) might be useful, after some thought I have decided that the added complexity and more cumbersome interface as well as probable reduced compiler support would outweigh any advantages, and therefore it would be easonable to support only separate chaining." So at some point it was considered to have a more extensible interface.

Comment: @ildjarn: in the same [thread](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2002/12/41117.php) it was also proposed to make "...a hash map and hash multimap in which a single value type is specified along with a traits class that is used to extract the key from the value type. The std::pair-specific hash_map and hash_multimap would then be based upon this generic implementation." Too bad this didn't make it into the final interface, as these two extra policies would have made the current std::unordered_map much easier adaptable to a wider range of use cases.

Comment: @rhalbersma : "*a traits class that is used to extract the key from the value type*" If this is what you're after then have a look at [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/), as that's exactly how it works. :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general-purpose way to perform operations on a hash without continuous access to the hash values. For example, suppose the hash internally uses a tree. To add a new node to the hash, you need to compare its hash value to the hash value of existing nodes on the tree. How can you do that if you didn't store their values in the tree?

What you're asking for is probably not impossible, but none of the typical hashing algorithms can do it. And there doesn't seem to be any point anyway, you have to store *something* to make the collection traversable, and it's hard to see how something other than the hash could ever work as well as the hash, since that's what you're searching for.

If the hash is "too big", use a hash of the hash. (Of course, then you have to deal with hash collisions.)

Comment: As far as I understand it, the OP isn't using the `hash<Key>` as the actual key, but rather the lower 32bits of it, while storing the upper 32bits together with the value in a pair.

Comment: Then just make the lower 32-bits of `hash<Key>` the `Key`. You still have to store it somewhere though, otherwise there's no way to traverse the hash to do inserts, finds, and deletes.

Comment: @David Schwartz: sorry if  I am ignorant about basic data structures, but how can a hash table be implemented using a tree and still have O(1) access time, other than using a random access array/vector as the internal data structure?

Comment: @rhalbersma If you use a *n* bit hash, the number of tree branches will never exceed *n* regardless of the number of elements stored. (It's O(1) with respect to the number of entries stored in it.)

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11 hashes are actually of type `size_t` you can do something along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
struct with_hash
{
    size_t hash;
    T value;
};

template<> struct std::hash<with_hash>
{
    typedef size_t result_type;
    typedef with_hash argument_type;
    size_t operator()(const with_hash &x)
    {
         return x.hash;
    }
};

template <typename T>
using perfectly_hashed = std::unordered_set< with_hash<T> >;
```

With a few more sintactic sugar here and there...

Comment: Nice idea, but it still stores the full hash. Based on the answer by David Schwartz, I am now convinced that what I want can only be coded from scratch, not by simple typedefs of an unordered container.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your hashing function for the type you want to use as a key, and then create a type to hold the hashed value and specialize std::hash on that type to just return the hash value. Now you can compute the hash, discard the data used to compute the hash, and stick the value and its hash in the map.

To retrieve a value you somehow reconstruct the key data, and then you can recompute the hash value, and then search the map for that hash.

Answer (score 1):

I may have gotten this completely wrong, but why not just a `std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::pair<uint32_t, Value>>` with some nice utility functions for insertion and extraction?

```
// demonstration with 32bit 'hash' and 16bit 'lo' and 'hi'
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    typedef std::unordered_map<uint16_t, std::pair<uint16_t, std::string>> map_type;
    map_type m;
    std::string key = "hello", value = "world";
    uint32_t hash = std::hash<std::string>()(key);
    uint16_t lo = hash & 0xFFFF, hi = hash >> 16; // make a nice function for this
    m.insert(std::make_pair(lo, std::make_pair(hi, value))); // and this
    auto it = m.find(lo); // and this
    std::cout << "hash: " << hash << '\n'
              << "lo: " << it->first << '\n'
              << "hi: " << it->second.first << '\n'
              << "lo | (hi << 16): " << (it->first | (uint32_t(it->second.first) << 16)) << '\n'
              << "value: " << it->second.second << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/fV7rJ).

Output:

```
hash: 1335831723
lo: 11435
hi: 20383
lo | (hi << 16): 1335831723
value: world
```

Comment: that's not quite what I was looking for. In your example, I would like to store only `std::make_pair(hi, value)` and store this at the location of `lo`. Your code gets location `lo`, but stores both `hi`, `lo` and `value`.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Are those 32bit really gone kill your performance or is there another reason you don't want them?

Comment: on 16 byte hash entries (signature + value), another 4 bytes means 25% more memory. Not gonna kill me, but everything counts. My own implementation uses a two-layered approach that first hashes the Key into a 64-bit integer, then splits it into 32-bit hi/low parts and stores `std::pair<hi, Value>` into the low-th entry of a std::vector. It is just 150 lines of code, but I am a bit annoyed it can't be done with just a few typedefs and re-using std::unordered_map.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: how can one store only the Value of a Key-Value pair, in a location based on std::hash? This would be useful if one uses a perfect hash function, i.e. one for which different Keys map to different hash indices (so there is never collision resolution required).

A perfect hash function is not sufficient.  Not only do you have to guarantee that there are no hash collisions, you also have to ensure that there are no **bucket** collisions.  Heck, you even have to ensure that the number of buckets *never* changes, since your data structure cannot discover the hash of a key.